# Javascript - how to split / divide revealing module into smaller parts?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

I would like to split / divide my module "Engine" into smaller parts (and keep it in one file).

Suppose I have a lot of code in a method "paintText()" - this code should be in in separate part.

How to do this?

My module "Engine" is like:

**HTML**

```
 <button type="button" id="addText">1. Add some text</button> 
 <button type="button" id="countText">2. Count letters</button> 
 <button type="button" id="addColor">3. Add color</button> 

<div id="elText"></div>
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
<div id="elCounter"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var Engine = (function(){
    var addTextButton = document.querySelector('#addText');
    var countButton = document.querySelector('#countText');
    var colorButton = document.querySelector('#addColor');

    var textArea = document.querySelector('#elText');
    var counter = document.querySelector('#elCounter');

    addTextButton.addEventListener('click', addText, false);
    countButton.addEventListener('click', showCounter, false);
    colorButton.addEventListener('click', paintText, false);

    // Engine function
    function addText( event ){
        textArea.innerHTML += '<br /> add some text';
    }
    // Engine function
    function showCounter( event ){
        counter.innerHTML = 'amount of liter = ' + textArea.innerText.length;
    }

    // ADDITION function - separate it as submodule!!!
    function paintText( event ){
        /*
            lot of code....
            lot of code....
        */
        textArea.style.backgroundColor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);// random color
    }

    return {
        paintText : paintText
    }
})();
```

It is simple - you can:
1. add some text
2. count letters
3. add background color.

[Working JSFiddle - "One big Module":](https://jsfiddle.net/simitte/njwpcr1f/3/)

I am trying to separate  "paintText()" method into submodule, but I don't know how to do this right way.

### Wrong way:

I created 2 modules "Engine" and "Color", it works but this is stupid to have 2 modules.

```
var Engine = (function(){
    (...)


    function randomColor( event ){

        Color.paintText( textArea )

    }
})();

//submodule
var Color = (function(){
    function paintText(){
    }
    return {
        paintText : paintText
    }
})();
```

[Working JSFiddle - "Splitted Module - wrong way"](https://jsfiddle.net/simitte/4h57sq0o/)

It know it should look like this (to keep all parts in one object) :

```
pseudo code:

app = {};

//engine
app.engine = function(){
... engine here
}

//additional submodule
app.color = function(){
... color here
}

//additional submodule
app.images = function(){
... images here
}
```

but I don't know how to make it work!

Help please.

Comment: I would recommend to start small and extract the "lots of code" into multiple helper functions, all in the scope of the original `Engine` revealing module IIFE.

Comment: Do you want the "submodule" to be public? If it could stay internal, just move the `Color` revealing module that you have (in the "wrong way") inside the main module IIFE.

Comment: submodule "Color" can be privete - it is just a part of "Engine".
@Bergi - I moved "Color" module into "Engine" so it is now "Module in Module": 
https://jsfiddle.net/simitte/magdr6th/1/
Is this correct way?

What about:
`app = {};
app.engine = function{}
app.color = function{}
app.validator = function{}`

Comment: @Lavender Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/g19Lszn4/

Comment: @Lavender Yes, except that the outer IIFE no longer `return`s anything, so `Engine` is `undefined` and no methods can be called from outside - which can't be called revealing module pattern any more. But if it works for you, go ahead.

Comment: @Lavender Regarding the style of putting everything on an `app` object, that's not much different from your "wrong way" approach. `app.color` is not a submodule of `app.engine` here, and both are public.

Comment: Thanks guys for your advices! I choce @Bergi way!